# Better way to do this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

This is what I'm doing now, how to do this without resorting to a subquery and without the php. I can just run it inside phpmyadmin directly:

```
   <?php

    $query = mysql_query(" SELECT node_id FROM embeds ");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $node_id = $row['node_id'];
        mysql_query(" INSERT INTO node_teaser(node_id, content) VALUES('$node_id', 'This is the teaser!') ");
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO node_teaser(node_id, content)
SELECT node_id, 'This is the teaser!' FROM embeds;
```